# Child theme edits only work with !important

Tags: css, wordpress

In my site's child theme some changes only take effect if I use !important. Is this proper procedure or is it more of a workaround? Is there a better technique more in line with best practices?

Comment: Could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly isn't best practice, you'll probably want to look into specificity in CSS.

If you have a Child theme you may want to give it a `body` class of say `my-child-theme`, then in your child theme CSS you can do;

```
.my-child-theme .child-theme-element { background: pink }
```

without the need for using `!important`

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. How do I add a body class?